# Need solution for syncing remote database with storage

Tags: android, retrofit

I have an android app for which I can't figure something out. Let me describe the current situation:

It's an app that (among other things) retrieves events from a REST API. These events can be saved (or favourited) and stored in local storage by the user and all saved events need to be showed on a dedicated page.
I want users to be able to use the app when the user is without internet connection. All the events need to be saved locally and updated when connected to the internet.

My event object has a "favourited" variable which is false by default (as an event isn't saved by default, of course) and will be true when the user saves the event.
The event page gets all the event objects from the local storage where this boolean is true.

So far so good, I easily managed to realize this.

Now for the actual problem:
When the user connects to the internet again, all locally saved events, should be updated by the events that are retrieved through the API. But because the default value of "favourited" is false by default, every already saved event will just become false again when you refresh the page.

How should I go about this?

Some details:
For local storage I use RoomDatabase and for the API I use retrofit.
I'm aware of `OnConflictStrategy` but there is no option to update. I thought about using the `OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE` but this would mean that if an event was updated, the user would not receive the update.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to store favorites in a separate table with event id and favorite flag? so it won't be affected by event table update.

Comment: I looked at that as well but I can't, not without creating a whole seperate event class. I guess I could always do that as a backup plan but it doesn't seem like the best way to go about it you know

Comment: No need to create a whole new event class. you can create a simple field class.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class UserFavorite{
       boolean favorite=false;
   }

   public class Event{
       //other fields in Event class
       @Embedded
       UserFavorite userFavorite; 
   }
```

Consider you are saving event details from API using Event class, and this Event class has field class (UserFavorite) with user favorite flag with default value false.

So you can change user favorite flag whenever you want, and it won't be affected by update using API.